# react native half circle styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I search but I can't find nothing similar this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncx7f.png)

How can I implement this with react?

Answer (score -1):

This seems like something to be created with canvas or svg. This can be done with CSS, but not sure why you will want to do that. Codepen has something similar: https://codepen.io/vineethtr/pen/xGjQOX

To create a circle

```
border-radius: 100%
```

Maybe you can take a look at react canvas. Have not tried it out myself https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas

Some example projects created with react and canvas:https://react.rocks/tag/Canvas